# Vue Test Utils. Trigger click event on child component that isn't a .vue file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js, vue-test-utils

I'm writing a test for a Vue component that has a child component that's using an `.svg` file rather than a `.vue` file.

My issue is that **triggering a click on this child component doesn't register and the spy isn't recording any subsequent function call.**

I'm using vue-test-utils, mocha & sinon.

MyComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <ChildComponent 
    @click="doSomething"
    data-test-id="open"
  />
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from "@/assets/imgs/something.svg" //Component is an svg file    

export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      return 'foo'
    }
  }
}   
</script>
```

My test file MyComponent.spec.js

```
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import { expect } from "chai";
import sinon from "sinon";
import MyComponent from "@/components/myComponent"
import ChildComponent from "@/assets/imgs/something.svg"

describe("MyComponent", () => {
  const component = shallowMount(MyComponent, {})
  const mockMethod = sinon.spy()
  const childComponent = component.find("[data-test-id='open']")
  component.setMethods({
    doSomething: mockMethod
  })
  childComponent.trigger("click")
  // childComponent.vm.$emit("click") //throws error 'TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined'

  expect(childComponent.exists()).to.be.true // Passes
  expect(mockMethod).to.have.been.called; // Fails. with message: 'expected spy to have been called at least once, but it was never called'
})
```

I've tried triggering the click using `childComponent.vm.$emit("click")` but this tells me that the child components `vm` is undefined.  I'm thinking this could be related to the fact that `childComponent` is a functional component or because it's not a `.vue` file.

I've also tried `childComponent.trigger("click")`, it doesn't error but it doesn't trigger the function call.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried calling the function in the template with the parenthesis, like `@click="doSomething()"`? In my case it solved the issue.